# R Session Aborted when loading mailR in R4.2.0

Tags: r, r-package, sendmailr

I have just updated to R4.2.0 (previously R3.2) and I now get R Session Aborted when loading the package on windows. Same error when running directly from R. Everything seems ok when I install the mailR package. I also updated all dependencies.
Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my RTools to the newest version, 4.2
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html

Then I uninstalled both rJava and mailR, and reinstalled them again after the update without any issue.

Just as a side note, after a lot of headaches in Linux with mailR, trying to keep my java libraries updated, I finally switched to a curl-based email library, emayili: https://datawookie.github.io/emayili/
I found those Java dependencies would crop up as issues a few times a year in different systems, and haven't had any of the same with the new libraries.